# How to retrieve a string correctly from an excel file using NPOI in C#

Tags: c#, excel, regex, parsing

I am an intern, I am programming in C# right now and I have to retrieve a string of characters from an excel file. This excel is actually results gathered after a chemical analysis called ICP from 2 different machines (as you can see below, the example 1 correspond to the machine called "thermo" and the other example for the machine called " Agilent").

This Excel is a one empty excel file configured where the user can copy and paste data and press some buttons to do some treatments. One of these is the fact that when you press the button, all items you will find in the column A, will be put in the cell B2 separated by semicolons like a list.

After retrieving this string in the cell B2, I should return it in another method which should split this string into 2 lists (Sample and Reference) using a regex. My problem is that I don't know if my initial string is returned correctly from the first method because when I am running the code, it's not working correctly, the string is split correctly but there are more elements than expected.

Here is my code :

```
using NPOI.SS.UserModel;
using NPOI.XSSF.UserModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace excel
{
    class Class1
    {
        public static string ReadExcel()
        {

            string filepath = @"C:\Users\Lionel84100\Desktop\Excel\fezfFzfe.xlsx";
            try
            {
                IWorkbook workbook = null;
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                if (filepath.IndexOf(".xlsx") > 0)
                {
                    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
                }
                else if (filepath.IndexOf(".xls") > 0)
                {
                    workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
                }

                ISheet sheet = workbook.GetSheet("Formatage_IM");
                if (sheet != null)
                {
                    int rowCount = sheet.LastRowNum;


                    for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)

                    {
                        IRow curRow = sheet.GetRow(i);

                        string cellValue1 = curRow.GetCell(1).StringCellValue;
                        
                        return cellValue1;
                    }

                }

            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            return "";
        }

        public static (List<string> sample, List<string> reference) parse()
        {
            string input = ReadExcel();

            Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(\s*;\s*)+|(\s*;\s*)+$");
            string output = regex.Replace(input, " ");
            
             
             List<string> sample = new List<string>();
             List<string> reference = new List<string>();
             string pattern = @"C-[0-9]{6}-S-[0-9]{3}( [0-9])?";
             Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern); 

           
            

             foreach (string term in output.Split(';').Select(s => s.Trim()).Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)))
             {

                 if (rgx.IsMatch(term))
                 {
                     sample.Add(term);
                     
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     reference.Add(term);
                    reference.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
                 }
             }

             return (sample, reference);


        }




        }
    }
```

In my main I am only calling the second method.

Examples of string of characters :

Example 1: "QC4 1000 ppm ; C-191108-S-0095 ; C-191108-S-0095 ; QC4 100 ppm ; QC4 1000 ppm ; Et 500 ppm ; Et 1000 ppm ; Et 2000 ppm ; "

Example2 : " ; C-210104-S-117 2 ; C-210104-S-118 1 ; C-210104-S-118 2 ; Ref 100ppm QC4 ; Ref 1000ppm QC4 ; "

error in my console more elements than expected:

[image]

The expected results :
Example 1 / list sample : C-191108-S-0095 ; C-191108-S-0095 ;  (This correspond to the name of the samples)

Example 1/ list reference : QC4 1000 ppm ;QC4 100 ppm ; QC4 1000 ppm ; Et 500 ppm ; Et 1000 ppm ; Et 2000 ppm ; " (this correspond to the names of references taken as reference values  to compare results after an chemical analysis)

Example 2 / list sample : C-210104-S-117 2 ; C-210104-S-118 1 ; C-210104-S-118 2

Example 2/ list reference : Ref 100ppm QC4 ; Ref 1000ppm QC4 ;

can you say where is  an error in my code please ?

Thank you for your comprehension.

Comment: Excel doesn't have list types. I suspect the Excel file was created by lazily double-clicking on a CSV using incompatible culture settings (in most European countries the list separator is `;`, not `,`) and saved as Excel without realizing that the entire line ended up in a single cell. The *real* solution is to fix the code that generated this Excel file, or tell whoever did this to use *import* the file from the `Data` menu with the correct settings

Comment: What do *you* want to do though? Read the data? Convert it to a CSV? Or a proper Excel file? If you want to get back to the original CSV, you can read the entire first column and write each value out to a file. If you want to read that data, you can append them to a StringBuilder, then use eg CsvHelper to read the CSV string.

Comment: PS: I have the same issue right now. A lazy partner sends us "Excel" files where the entire line in in the first cell. While *the business people* are trying to convince the partner to get serious, I'm exporting the cell values to a CSV file by simply appending the values to the file.

Comment: what do you mean by " lazily double-clicking on a CSV using incompatible culture settings (in most European countries the list separator is ;, not ,) and saved as Excel without realizing that the entire line ended up in a single cell. "?  I don't understand.  and how should I do this "use import the file from the Data menu with the correct settings  " ?

Comment: I want to manipulate the data (string of the excel) by spliting it into to list. We use this to check if the element in the sample list are in the good status in a database in the LIMS ( a software developement used in laboratory).

Comment: In that case, the data is bad to begin with. Excel has no list values. It's EXTREMELY  unusual to find such text in Excel files. Most of the time, they appear due to bugs or human error - someone opened a CSV file with Excel and saved it to `xlsx` without noticing or caring about the bad data. If you wanted to store multiple values per row, use extra columns.

Comment: I suspect Excel has nothing to do with the problem, and even if you saved the data into a CSV, you'd still have problems. Is the *real problem* how to parse `QC4 1000 ppm ; C-191108-S-0095 ; C-191108-S-0095 ; QC4 100 ppm ; QC4 1000 ppm ; Et 500 ppm ; Et 1000 ppm ; Et 2000 ppm ;`? This has nothing to do with Excel. You'd have the same problem with a text file (which is probably preferable here). What are the parsing rules? What are the expected results from the two examples?

Comment: In fact I did the exel, what i mean by that is that I have configured one empty excel file where the user can copy and paste data and press some buttons to do some treatments. One of these is the fact that when you press the button, all items you will find in the colunm A, will be put in the cell B2 separated by semicolons like a list.

Comment: The parsing rules are for each element in the string, if it correspond to the regex, this element will go in the sample list and if it doesn't correspond it will go in the reference list.

Comment: The expected results :                                                                                           
Example 1 / list sample :  C-191108-S-0095 ; C-191108-S-0095 ;                                Example 1/ list reference : QC4 1000 ppm ;QC4 100 ppm ; QC4 1000 ppm ; Et 500 ppm ; Et 1000 ppm ; Et 2000 ppm ; "                                                                               Example 2 / list sample :  C-210104-S-117 2 ; C-210104-S-118 1 ; C-210104-S-118 2      Example 2/ list reference :   Ref 100ppm QC4 ; Ref 1000ppm QC4 ;

Comment: Edit the question and add the information there, properly formatted so it's clear what you want. It's very hard to read code in comments. Data becomes almost unreadable. And repeating what you already posted in the question doesn't explain anything

Comment: I have edited the post

Comment: `if it correspond to the regex,` that's not a parsing rule. That's how you think the parsing rule should be implemented. The only thing we know is you have a bunch of things separated by semicolons. What are those things? What is a `QC4 1000 ppm`, how does it differ from `Et 500 ppm` or `C-191108-S-0095` or `Ref 100ppm QC4` ? If we call those things Bloops, it looks like each Bloop contains 1 or 3 Zonks.

Comment: `I have edited the post` you didn't. You repeated what you already posted hours ago without any explanation. You're asking people to guess what you have and what you want. Or try to reverse-engineer what you want from a regular expression that doesn't work

Comment: Youo haven't explained what the problem is either. The screenshot shows some specific strings. Was it supposed to display something else? Does the regular expression work at all with ` C-191108-S-0095 `? Have you tried debugging the code ? If the match fails, have you checked what those strings actually contain?

Comment: I am sorry for the misunderstanding, I hope you will understand better now

Comment: It is suppose to contain only what i said in the expected results in my post, actually there is more references names than needed, it's the same for the sample list.  The regex fonction for all types of ` C-191108-S-0095 `. I have tried to debug but there is nothing that I could see.

Comment: Your `parse` method calls the `ReadExcel` method. If you put a breakpoint on this line: `Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(\s*;\s*)+|(\s*;\s*)+$");` and hover over `input`, what value do you see? (NB Update the question with this information, and don't forget to include `\`` before and after the value.)

Comment: I see :  excel.Class1.ReadExcel returned -> values :"; QC4 1000 ppm;......"           and imput - >  Value : null